# music player "file not found" exception?

Tags: java, file, embedded-resource, javasound

I'm try to add a soundtrack to a simple little java game, and I've researched how to do it to the extent that I have code that compiles. However, when I run it, I get a FileNotFound exception. I'm using Eclipse and my wav file is in the same directory as the .class files.

Here's my exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: bach.wav (No such file or directory)

And my code for the music player:

```
public static void play()
{
  try
  {
      Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
      clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("bach.wav")));
      clip.start();
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
      exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Is this an applet or a desktop application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you say `new File("bach.wav")` you have to put the file in the root folder of your project where the src and bin folders are

Comment: That will likely fail at time of deployment.  @Reimeus has supplied the best strategy.

Comment: @andrew true, if you plan to deploy the project, reimeus solution should be used.

Answer (score 2):

`AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream` has an [overloaded method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream%28java.net.URL%29) that takes a `URL`. This will use a buffered stream as required. As the `.wav` file is in the same location as the class file, you could use `getResource`:

```
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("bach.wav"));
```

As `play` is `static` you will need:

```
AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(MyClass.class.getResource("bach.wav"));
```

Comment: The stream for `getAudioInputStream` needs to be buffered, while the stream returned from `getResourceAsStream` is not buffered.  Shorter (in a number of ways) is to use `getResource` for an `URL` as seen in the [Java Sound tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).

Comment: Good point. I had `getResource` originally so have changed it back. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

try change:

```
new File("bach.wav")
```

to:

```
new File("bach.wav").getAbsolutePath()
```